# How do I pass variable from let to shared example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refactoring

I have a test like this:

```
describe 'event creation' do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  ...
  it_behaves_like 'also creates public_activity record', user
end
```

I need user record to check if public_activity was created correctly, but example above is not working, since variables from let are only accessible from example context.

I made this workaround:

```
describe 'event creation' do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  ...

  describe 'public activity' do
    before { @user = user }
    it_behaves_like 'also creates public_activity record', @user
  end
end
```

It works, but I don't like this approach very much. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `include_examples` instead of `it_behaves_like`. Then test cases will use current context.